# Basis for space of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**STATEMENT:** Let $\left\{v_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $V$ and $\left\{w_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ a basis for W. Prove that a basis of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. is
$$T_{i,j}(v_k) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       w_j & : k=i\\
       0 & : k\neq i
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

**QUESTION:** It seems this set only forms a basis if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional. I was wondering if I am mistaken or does this in fact extend to cases where $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional?

Comment: BTW $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is the space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This definition looks perfectly good for infinite cases.</strike> See below.

Comment: But what if $I,J=\mathbb{N}$ and we took the map $T$ where $v_i\mapsto w_i$. Wouldn't we have to take an infinite sum of elements $T_{i,j}$? Namely, $T=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}T_{i,i}$. Contradicting the fact that $T_{i,j}$ forms a basis.

Comment: Yes, so this is dealt with in the usual way for infinite dimensional vectors spaces: a set of vectors $B = \{ v_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$ in some vector space $V$ is linearly independent if the only finite linear combination of the $v_\lambda$s that is zero is the trivial linear combination. Similarly, we define $B$ to be a basis iff every element of $V$ can be written in a unique way as a finite linear combination of elements of $B$.

Comment: I understand how basis elements are dealt with in infinite dimensional spaces, but what I am saying is that our set of maps $T_{i,j}$ as a sum equals our given map $T$(given in my above comment) only as a finite sum. So therefore $T_{i,j}$ can't span $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ if $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional.

Comment: If it is a basis could you possibly find a finite sum of elements $T_{i,j}$ that equals the map $T$ that I gave in my first comment. I want to clarify some of the confusion I have with the map $T$ I gave in the first comment. Also note that $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ based on my definition.

Comment: Damn it, you're right; sorry for the misdirection. Take $V = W = C^\infty[0,1]$. Then differentiation $D$ is a linear operator. But there's no way to write $D$ as a finite sum of such $T_{i,j}$.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.